# Concatenate an array within a shell script to create file paths for backups

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to create a simple backup script before a system upgrade.

I want to have an array of file paths(BACKUP_DIRS) which then get concatenated into another variable(SOURCE_DIRS) that will be used for backups using tar

I am having difficulty with joining the array into a single variable that is spaced.

```
#!/bin/bash

BACKUP_DIRS=(
~/.ssh/
~/workspace/
~/Downloads/
)             

# Concat paths
SOURCE_DIRS=''
for DIR in "${BACKUP_DIRS[@]}"
do
    $SOURCE_DIRS = $SOURCE_DIRS' '$DIR
done

# Backup
tar -czf backup.tar.gz $SOURCE_DIRS
```

Comment: All-caps names are used by variables with meaning to the operating system or shell itself, whereas the namespace of names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use. Correspondingly, you should be using lowercase names for your own variables to avoid inadvertent conflicts. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: BTW, consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: To get an string, this is enough: `echo "${BACKUP_DIRS[*]}"` (with a default value for IFS).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why create one string `SOURCE_DIRS` when you could just use

```
tar -czf backup.tar.gz "${BACKUP_DIRS[@]}"
```

The array version expands to `/my/first entry`, `/the/second entry`, `...` where the one string version would be interpreted as `/my/first`, `entry`, `/the/second`, `entry`, `...`. Therefore your old approach probably wouldn't work as exepected for paths with spaces in them.

Comment: certainly is a better sollution